# Ports not Showing When running Docker-compose ps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello Everyone… I am using docker for the first time
And I am attempting to host a python script on a docker container from my windows 10 laptop
The issue is that… the container starts successfully, but when I run docker-compose ps I can’t see the ports I defined in the docker-compose file.

Here are my codes

**Docker File**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /.

COPY script.py /

CMD [ "python", "./script.py"  ]
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
   build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dockerfile
   ports:
    - "80:80"
```

**Python Script**

```
import json as j, urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/victorebhojie/devopsproject/master/data.json") as url:

    d = j.loads(url.read().decode())

import xml.etree.cElementTree as e        

r = e.Element("Employee")

e.SubElement(r,"Name").text = d["Name"]

e.SubElement(r,"Designation").text = d["Designation"]

e.SubElement(r,"Salary").text = str(d["Salary"])

e.SubElement(r,"Age").text = str(d["Age"])

a = e.ElementTree(r)

a.write("/tmp/json_to_xml.xml")
```

and here is the docker-compose ps output:

```
  Name                Command         State    Ports
---------------------------------------------------------
devopsproject_web_1   python ./script.py   Exit 0
```

Please can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You ask the same question in the [Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-see-ports-when-running-docker-compose-ps/102522) and I gave the answer there.

Comment: There is no exposed port in your script. Your scripts runs and ends eventually.

Comment: Yes, I verified the answer. thanks

Comment: @MehrdadEP I have added and EXPOSE to my docker file. docker-compose show the port bindings, but I still can't open in a browser.. pardon me, I'm very new to docker

Comment: @Tekki from my script can you deduce why it doesn't open in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the docker image that you are using is not using any port by default. But you have bound the 80 port of docker container to the VM in `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you want to see the port is getting used or not. Please check by executing the below command:

```
docker ps
```

or

```
netstat -nltp
```

and look for port `80`. Please let me know if it doesn't help you.

Comment: hi Pandav, I have added and EXPOSE to my docker file. docker-compose show the port bindings, but I still can't open in a browser.. pardon me, I'm very new to docker

Comment: I agree you have added the port in your docker-compose.yml file but the service that you are trying to run is not using port 80 because of that only. you are not able to access it from a browser. I suggest you run this service locally and check if it is using 80 port and you are able to access it from the browser or not.